# Using annotation properties in SpEL expression

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

I want to create an annotation with a parameter that will extend @PreAuthorize:

```
@Inherited
@PreAuthorize("@levelService.verify(#level)")
public @interface LevelAuthGuard {
    int level() default 0;
}
```

But #level (or #level()) in SpEL isn't accessible and I don't understand why:
SpEL can use method parameters.
Class-level SpEL annotation initializes on "compile" time, but level property is defined on compile time as well and can't be changed. Same as spel string that is passed into @PreAuthorize annotation.
How to do that without custom AoP bean/configuration and, most important, WHY it doesn't have access to annotation property?

Comment: The reason for "why" this doesn't work is probably that it isn't implemented ("features are unimplemented by default"). I think the more interesting question is how to still do that.

Comment: With "default 0;" it has default value on compile time, without default it doesn't even compile because I didn't define the value when used annotation. From what I know it isn't even possible to change annotation value on runtime

Comment: Do you mean it "works" if you ignore the default value and add the level explicitely (i.e. `@LevelAuthGuard(0)`)?

Comment: No, the SpEL expression doesn't have access to the property at all and fails when the expression is executed in runtime. The only way I made it work is to create multiple annotations (Level1AuthGuard, Level2AuthGuard) and explicitly put a number in spel), but this solution is unacceptable for 3+ annotations

Comment: Yeah, this is what I meant with my initial comment. The reason for that (since you have asked for WHY this wouldn't work) is probably that it wouldn't be implemented on Spring's side.